# php banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

alguém pode me ajudar,quero que apareça apenas os registros do usuario logado,so que ta aparecendo de todos....

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: posta o código ao invés de imagem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa do `id_usuario` que está logado, acredito que já tenha isso em mãos, pois o problema esta aqui:

```
$id_usuario = $_SESSION["id_usuario"];

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario = $id_usuario";
```

Faltou vc definir a igualdade dentro da consulta.

Agora uma duvida minha, qual a necessidade de duas variáveis iguais?

```
$consulta = $consulta =
```

Comment: '$consulta = $consulta = ' foi erro de digitação,de resto me ajudou muito,obrigado mano

Comment: QUe bom, amigo, qualquer coisa só postar ai no grupo.